# Find out number of capture groups in Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to determine how many capture groups there are in a given regular expression?

I would like to be able to do the follwing:

```
def groups(regexp, s):
    """ Returns the first result of re.findall, or an empty default

    >>> groups(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)', '123')
    ('1', '2', '3')
    >>> groups(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)', 'abc')
    ('', '', '')
    """
    import re
    m = re.search(regexp, s)
    if m:
        return m.groups()
    return ('',) * num_of_groups(regexp)
```

This allows me to do stuff like:

```
first, last, phone = groups(r'(\w+) (\w+) ([\d\-]+)', 'John Doe 555-3456')
```

However, I don't know how to implement `num_of_groups`. (Currently I just work around it.)

**EDIT:** Following the [advice from rslite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127055/find-out-number-of-capture-groups-in-python-regular-expressions/127089#127089), I replaced `re.findall` with `re.search`.

`sre_parse` seems like the most robust and comprehensive solution, but requires tree traversal and appears to be a bit heavy.

MizardX's regular expression seems to cover all bases, so I'm going to go with that.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
def num_groups(regex):
    return re.compile(regex).groups
```

Comment: This won't actually return the number of groups, it will return a tuple of all of the groups. In order to return the number of groups, you'll need the following code (in Python 3.4): `return len(re.compile(regex).groups())`

Comment: @RaziShaban `re.compile(regex).groups` is a property of type `int`. `re.compile(regex).match(input).groups()` is a method, returning a `tuple`.

Comment: right, sorry, I was working with findall, not compile. Point I was making is that your function is named `num_groups` but returns a tuple, not a number.

Comment: I like using just  len(match.groups())   after having done a match = re.search() or whatever returns you a match object.

Answer (score 36):

```
f_x = re.search(...)
len_groups = len(f_x.groups())
```

Comment: Thanks, the best one. No need to compile anything, it's already done.

Comment: This will not work if the search fails. f_x will be None in that case, so it won't have a "groups" property to check.

Comment: @nupanick so need to check `if f_x: 
len(f_x.groups())`

Comment: I feel this is better. Because this can also be used to see how many matches were made, as well as how many groups are there by using len(), whereas the accepted/compile answer only gives an integer = how many groups are there

Answer (score 3):

Something from inside sre_parse might help.

At first glance, maybe something along the lines of:

```
>>> import sre_parse
>>> sre_parse.parse('(\d)\d(\d)')
[('subpattern', (1, [('in', [('category', 'category_digit')])])), 
('in', [('category', 'category_digit')]), 
('subpattern', (2, [('in', [('category', 'category_digit')])]))]
```

I.e. count the items of type 'subpattern':

```
import sre_parse

def count_patterns(regex):
    """
    >>> count_patterns('foo: \d')
    0
    >>> count_patterns('foo: (\d)')
    1
    >>> count_patterns('foo: (\d(\s))')
    1
    """
    parsed = sre_parse.parse(regex)
    return len([token for token in parsed if token[0] == 'subpattern'])
```

Note that we're only counting root level patterns here, so the last example only returns 1. To change this, *tokens* would need to searched recursively.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you only need the first result of re.findall it's better to just use re.search that returns a match or None.

For the groups number you could count the number of open parenthesis '(' except those that are escaped by '\'. You could use another regex for that:

```
def num_of_groups(regexp):
    rg = re.compile(r'(?<!\\)\(')
    return len(rg.findall(regexp))
```

Note that this doesn't work if the regex contains non-capturing groups and also if '(' is escaped by using it as '[(]'. So this is not very reliable. But depending on the regexes that you use it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code as a basis:

```
def groups(regexp, s):
    """ Returns the first result of re.findall, or an empty default

    >>> groups(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)', '123')
    ('1', '2', '3')
    >>> groups(r'(\d)(\d)(\d)', 'abc')
    ('', '', '')
    """
    import re
    m = re.search(regexp, s)
    if m:
        return m.groups()
    return ('',) * len(m.groups())
```

Comment: This will throw an exception when no match is found

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong, but I don't think there is a way to find the number of groups that would have been returned had the regex matched.  The only way I can think of to make this work the way you want it to is to pass the number of matches your particular regex expects as an argument.

To clarify though: When findall succeeds, you only want the first match to be returned, but when it fails you want a list of empty strings?  Because the comment seems to show all matches being returned as a list.